# How far in advance can an American come to Canada before their student visa starts?

Tags: canada, study, student-visas

I'm wondering how far in advance I can come to Canada from America on a student visa before my school starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can travel to Canada as soon as you receive your letter of introduction and your passport is returned to you from the consulate. It will already contain a valid visa if your nationality requires a visa to travel to Canada; otherwise Canada will automatically have given you an eTA if your nationality requires one. You need to bring the letter of introduction, your passport and possibly [other documents](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/study-canada/study-permit/prepare-arrival.html) with you when you travel to Canada; your actual study permit will be issued to you at the border when you present your documents to the CBSA border officer.

The letter of introduction will specify the *latest* date which you can enter Canada; if you do not enter on or before that date, you will not be able to obtain your study permit or study in Canada.

Comment: Thank you so much! So to be clear, I wouldn't need a visitor visa to enter Canada early if I have a student visa?

Comment: @DanielleZak No, you don't need a separate visa.

Comment: In this subsequent question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/152529/can-a-canadian-sponsor-american-to-study-in-canada_ the OP says she's Canadian...in which case she wouldn't need a visa at all.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Yes sorry I was asking this question on my boyfriends behalf. Im Canadian, and he's american! He wants to study in Canada.

Comment: @DanielleZak A US ciitzen will not need either visa or eTA to travel to Canada, but all the rest still applies. I'll leave the answer as is, because people of other nationalities may benefit from it as well. One important note is that he should ask the border officer to stamp his passport; the school will probably require it, and Canada doesn't routinely stamp Americans' passports.

Comment: It's a good idea to get a preapproved study permit especially in an unclear sponsor situation like OP's. Usually US citizens and PRs can also just apply for a study permit at a port of entry without preapproval (PRs still need to apply for eTA if they are flying).