# Can a Canadian sponsor American to study in Canada?

Tags: study, visa-sponsors

My American partner is looking to study in Canada, can I as a Canadian sponsor him to study financially?

Comment: In your earlier question _https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/152525/how-far-in-advance-can-an-american-come-to-canada-before-their-student-visa-star_ you say you're an American citizen going to Canada to study using a Canadian-issued student visa. In this question, you say you're Canadian and it's your partner who's going to Canada. Please clarify.

Comment: Yes sorry, I am Canadian, my partner is american. I would like to financially support him to study in Canada. Is that possible?